# help with methods

Tags: java

I think my program should run, I'm just blanking on how to call these methods so it will work. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class median {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // need to call methods

    }
    int[] arr;
    int m;
    public void selectionSort() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("how many numbers in array: ");
         m = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter"+m+" numbers: ");
        int count=0;
        while(count <m){
            int num = input.nextInt();
            arr[count]=num;
        }

          int i, j, minIndex, tmp;
          int n = arr.length;
          for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                minIndex = i;
                for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                      if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex])
                            minIndex = j;
                if (minIndex != i) {
                      tmp = arr[i];
                      arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
                      arr[minIndex] = tmp;
                }
          }
    }
    public void median(){
        if (m%2==0){
            double median = (arr[m/2]+arr[(m/2)+1])/2;
            System.out.println("the median is "+median);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("the median is "+arr[(m/2)+1] );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Design note (off topic, but needs saying): Your functions are each doing more than one thing (calculating/processing the data, as well as doing console I/O).  You may want to consider splitting the I/O code off to separate functions.

Comment: add `System.exit(1);` in your main method and you're program will work as expected. Seriously, what are you trying to accomplish? What is your rationale?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `static` modifier to your methods and fields. If you don't understand why, I recommend you read the [Learning the Java Language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) tutorial.

Comment: Or create an instance within `main`, and use that.

Comment: @cHao, Right, I know. I'm just not sure what OP is trying to accomplish here, so I went for the general solution. I'll remove my answer is this solution isn't suitable.

Answer (score 3):

**First**: create an object from that class.
**Second**: call the methods.

Like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // need to call methods

        //creating object
        Median m = new Median();

        //calling methods from the object
        m.selectionSort();
        m.median();
    }
```

**UPDATE:** You don't need to create the constructor unless you want to put some customized code in it.

**PS:** Class names: first letter in **always in capitals** = best practices.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   median m1 = new median();
   m1.selectionSort();
   m1.median();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of yourself, and invoke the methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  median me = new median();
  me.selectionSort();
}
```

Incidentally, you should consider renaming `median` to be `Median` to conform with Java class naming conventions.